# react-native-elements + Next.js gives “Module parse failed: Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.”

Tags: react-native, next.js, expo, react-native-elements

I have a combined Expo/React Native + Next.js project (native + web app), based on Expo’s instructions (see [guide](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/), [@expo/next-adapter](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/tree/main/packages/next-adapter), [code example](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-nextjs)).

Source code: https://github.com/tomsoderlund/reactnative-nextjs-template/pull/1

It works fine until I tried to add `react-native-elements`; now it gives a Webpack error when running inside Next.js with `yarn dev` (it works fine with React Native `yarn dev:native`).

I’ve [added the new modules to `transpilePackages`](https://github.com/tomsoderlund/reactnative-nextjs-template/pull/1/files#diff-882b2c04b01b2e8b2cdcf1817c30ea503a8005f1c0d54cfff37053b6801fea85R10) in `next.config.js`.

Error message:

```
./node_modules/react-native-ratings/dist/SwipeRating.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (171:43)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   const { imageSize, ratingCount, type, tintColor } = this.props;
|   const { source } = TYPES[type];
>   return times(ratingCount, index => <View key={index} style={styles.starContainer}>
|   <Image source={source} style={{ width: imageSize, height: imageSize, tintColor }}/>
| </View>);
```

### Update: next-transpile-modules

After reading in the Expo guide:

> You might need to use the `next-transpile-modules` plugin to transpile certain third-party modules in order for them to work (such as Emotion).

...I tried adding `next-transpile-modules` to my `next.config.js`, but later learned it’s redundant: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-1#built-in-module-transpilation-stable

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error. No idea what to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note: `next-transpile-modules` has now been built into Next.js as of 13.1: https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules/releases/tag/the-end

Comment: Thanks Lee! Still struggling with “Module parse failed” though…